# how to count the number of a certain character in a list of list of string in python version 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

input:

`animals= [['dog', 'snake', 'snake'], ['dog', 'dog', 'cat'], ['snake', 'snake', 'cat']]`

```
    animal_to_count = ['dog', 'cat']
```

output:

`animal_found = [3, 2]`

I have a list of list of strings. I want to count the number of each animals in that list of list of string.

I tried to do this with a for loop to target them individually:

```
def find_animals(animals: List[List]str, animals_to_count: List[str]) -> List[int]

counts = [0, 0]
    for char in animals:
       for s in char:
           if s in animal_to_count:
               counts=counts+1
               return counts
```

Now this is the part where I am bugging, I know I am supposed to use counts so that every time the loops goes by, it add it to the count, but the problem is I don't know how to do it. When I do what is above, I get an error. This is for an assignment, and I would like to find the answer without using any built-in function (beside all of the list method, string method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work:

```
animals= [['dog', 'snake', 'snake'], ['dog', 'dog', 'cat'], ['snake', 'snake', 'cat']]
animal_to_count = ['dog', 'cat']

results = []
for sublist in animals:
    results_per_animal_count = []
    for count_animal in animal_to_count:
        counter = 0
        for animal in sublist:
            if animal == count_animal:
                counter += 1
        results_per_animal_count.append(counter)
    results.append(results_per_animal_count)
```

The printout of `results` is

```
[[1, 0], [2, 1], [0, 1]]
```

#### EDIT

If you want to get the aggregated list you can use:

```
animals= [['dog', 'snake', 'snake'], ['dog', 'dog', 'cat'], ['snake', 'snake', 'cat']]
animal_to_count = ['dog', 'cat']

results = []

for count_animal in animal_to_count:
    counter = 0
    for sublist in animals:
        for animal in sublist:
            if animal == count_animal:
                counter += 1
    results.append(counter)
```

Where the print out of results is:

```
[3, 2]
```

#### EDIT 2

```
animals= [['dog', 'snake', 'snake'], ['dog', 'dog', 'cat'], ['snake', 'snake', 'cat']]
animal_to_count = ['snake'] # here you add and remove search items

results = []

for count_animal in animal_to_count:
    counter = 0
    for sublist in animals:
        for animal in sublist:
            if animal == count_animal:
                counter += 1
    results.append(counter)
```

printout

```
[4]
```

Comment: what do they mean? what is [[1, 0], [2, 1], [0, 1]] for?

Comment: It gives you the count of dog and cat per sublist. So in the first list there is 1 mention of dog and no mention of cat, therefore `[1,0]`.

Comment: I added the aggregated version too :)

Comment: OH MY GOD THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCHHHHHHHHHHHHHH THANK YOU VERY MUCH YOU ARE SAVING MY LIFE!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: now that I have this, is there a way to count the number of snake? and get it as a single list with one int? so for ['dog', 'cat'] I would get [3, 2] but in the same function if I wanted to get ['snake'] and get [4], how would I do that? Currently I added result_snake = [] and count_snake = 0, but because we have for count_animal in animal_to_count, the result i get is [4, 8].

Comment: you can compare the each string with 'snake' using for loop and increase the counter by one every time it has a match with string, then append the final count in the list.

Comment: @FamilySultani, I added the example

Answer (score 1):

You should count "dog" and "cat" separately. Something like this:

```
def find_animals(animals, animals_to_count):
    counts = [0]*len(animals_to_count)
    for items in animals:
        for item in items:
            for index, animal_to_count in enumerate(animals_to_count):
                if item==animal_to_count:
                    counts[index]+=1
    return counts
```

`[0]*len(animals_to_count)` creates a list with as many zeros as there are elements in animals_to_count

Comment: but animal_to_count will not always be with 2 animal inside, it can have 4 or 10, and I cannot do that when I don't know how long will animal_to_count be.

Answer (score 0):

This will return dictionary containing counts for each animal in the list.

```
def find_animals(animals:List[List], animals_to_count: List[str]):
  d = {}
  for animal in animals_to_count:
    d[animal] = 0

  for char in animals:
    for s in char:
        if s in animals_to_count:
          d[s] += 1

  return d

res = find_animals(animals,animals_to_count)
print('Dogs:',res['dog'],' ','Cats:',res['cat'])
```

Comment: when I do that, it gives me 5, it gives me the total, but I need to find them separately.

Comment: i have made necessary changes, hope this will help.